# MAMP server configuration error + PHP & MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, imagick

I'm attempting to use MAMP on a windows laptop, so I can run a JavaScript experiment for my Phd. Unfortunately I can't seem to get past startup.
When I open Mamp and select 'Start Servers' the following message pops up:

> MAMP could not start servers as configuration is not valid. Please check logs...

Despite this message the Apache Server and My SQL Server boxes turn green to suggest they are active.

After looking through a few logs I find the following errors, but I'm not sure how to address or fix them.

**Apache_error.log**

> [Sat Mar 03 08:10:15 2018] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

**Php_error.log**

> [02-Mar-2018 21:10:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.7\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
>    in Unknown on line 0

**Mampapp.log**

> textMessage:The description for Event ID '-1073741724' in Source 'MySQL' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'D:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '5.6.34-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   '
>   Source:MySQL
>   Category:(0)
>   EntryType:Information
>   EventID:100

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need it to be MAMP for a reason? You may use XAMPP or WAMP on a windows machine

Comment: I'll try WAMP. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

MAMP is for mac specific. You would better take Xamp cross-platform (personal recommendation) or Wamp that is windows specific.

Comment: Well that answers that! Thankyou

Comment: If this helps you and also understand why, can you maybe accept this answer. Would help me as well ;)